# Syncing audio with lyrics

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to sync an audio file and a lyrics file(String format). After following many posts on SO, I tried using Speech To Text to get the text from audio. But it doesn't listen the audio,it waits for the speech. And lyrics file need to be converted into an SRT file in accordance with the song. How could the below be possible?

1. Listening to audio file playing using TTS ? Is this the right way to do it?
2. How to convert lyrics file(string format) into an SRT file ?

Any suggestions/guidance will be greatly appreciated. 
The below code waits for me to speak some words.But I need it to listen to the audio file playing.
Code I have tried so far :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);       
    sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());    


 class listener implements RecognitionListener          
   {
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
            }
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
            }
            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged");
            }
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onBufferReceived");
            }
            public void onEndOfSpeech()
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onEndofSpeech");
            }
            public void onError(int error)
            {
                String mError=null;
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);


                 switch (error) {
                 case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:                
                     mError = " network timeout"; 
                     sr.startListening(intent);
                     break;
                 case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK: 
                     mError = " network" ;
                     //toast("Please check data bundle or network settings");
                     return;
                 case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO: 
                     mError = " audio"; 
                     break;
                 case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER: 
                     mError = " server"; 
                     sr.startListening(intent);

                     break;
                 case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT: 
                     mError = " client"; 
                     break;
                 case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT: 
                     mError = " speech time out" ; 
                     break;
                 case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH: 
                     mError = " no match" ; 
                     sr.startListening(intent);


                     break;
                 case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY: 
                     mError = " recogniser busy" ; 
                     break;
                 case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS: 
                     mError = " insufficient permissions" ; 
                     break;

                 }    

                Log.d(TAG,  "error " +  mError);

            }
            public void onResults(Bundle results)                   
            {
                     String str = new String();
                     Log.d(TAG, "onResults " + results);
                     ArrayList data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                     for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
                     {
                               Log.d(TAG, "result " + data.get(i));
                               str += data.get(i);
                     }

            }
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResults");
            }
            public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onEvent " + eventType);
            }
   }

public void onSongPicked()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

        sr.startListening(intent);}
```